# c++ LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I have a DLL I was handed down by a device manufacturer.
I can effortlessly call all its functions from a MS Console application (not from Qt or C++ Builder) but not from an MFC/WinAPI application? In an effort to work around the problem, I'm exploring the LoadLibrary() route. I am experimenting with this code, in VS2019 :

```
   HINSTANCE hInstance = LoadLibrary(L"DEVICE.dll");
   int(*fnDLLFuncAddress)(void) = (int(*)(void))GetProcAddress(hInstance2, "Device_RegisterDeviceEventHandler");
```

I have the impression that the code is working since this is the fnDLLFunAddress content :

```
fnDLLFuncAddress = DEVICE.dll!0x00007ffa66adda20 (load symbols for additional information)
```

Two questions, if I may. First, where would I look for "load symbols for additional information"? And the second, less obvious, is, once I have the Function address, in the form of a pointer, do I simply use the explicitely linked function name in lieu of the original function call to the DLL?

To start the program, I need to launch the following Event Handler, defined this way :

```
DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES __stdcall FPtr_Device_RegisterDeviceEventHandler(const FPtr_DeviceEventHandler inHandler);
```

In main(), the way I'm expected to launch the DeviceHandler is with this call :

```
deviceError = fnDLLFuncAddress(EventNotice);
```

Where "deviceError" is defined in DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES enum.
The EventNotice function is defined this way :

```
void EventNotice(EventCode outEventCode, uint32 outRAWDataCount, DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES outError);
```

When I try to execute the call, the compiler complains with E0140 "Too many arguments in function call" and E0513 "a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES".

My intuition tells me I should try supplying the "EventNotice" function address in the function call? Is it simply a matter of "dereferencing" the function name like "*EventNotice"?

If this was to work, I guess I'd still have to resolve the "incompatible" return type of the RegisterDeviceHandler call?

Any help is appreciated.

=== additional note ===================

The reason I'm having difficulty, I think, is because I am unable to replicate the original "RegisterDeviceHandler" function prototype?

With GetProAddress(), I'm able to get a pointer to the function address in the DLL but that does not give me the corresponding "function declaration"?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Qt, and everything to do with C++.  Is `EventNotice` your function, or a *prototype* provided by the author that describes what an `EventNotice` function's signature should be?  If it's the latter, then what you would have done is create a function, doesn't matter the name, but *must* match the signature given by the author for `EventNotice`.

Comment: Symbols: you'd get them from the author of the DLL, but you probably won't get them and won't need them. About your call, you need to define the function type correctly. You defined it as returning `int` and taking no arguments (`(void)`) but you are calling it with a `const FPtr_Device_DeviceEventHandler` as argument and expect a `DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES` return value

Comment: But you also need to make sure that you specify `__stdcall` in your type, otherwise you will crash because the default is `__cdecl`

Comment: `DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES (__stdcall * fnDLLFuncAddress)(const FPtr_Device_DeviceEventHandler)` instead of `int (* fnDLLFuncAddress)(void)` - does that work? The rest looks OK

Comment: But can you elaborate what's the issue with using the (presumably) provided import library? After all you mentioned it worked fine in a console application.

Comment: What bugs me is, why in the Console application, the compiler is not complaining about the "number of arguments" used in the RegisterDeviceHandler(EventNotice) function call. FYI, EventNotice is not part of the DLL, it uses three arguments.

Comment: @CherryDT : The story of my project is simple. I was given a Sample.cpp console application with a DLL, a LIB and a few Header files. When I run this code, I'm able to send commands and receive data from the device. The problem arose when I tried to switch the code to a GUI environment, such as MFC or WinAPI. I was gung ho about C++ Builder but when I saw that it could not run my Sample.cpp without complaining about "Unresolved References", I was discouraged. I later tried a Qt console application but got the same "Unresolved References". I can't see what's wrong with this DLL.

Comment: @RogerBreton -- *With GetProAddress(), I'm able to get a pointer to the function address in the DLL but that does not give me the corresponding "function declaration"?* -- No it doesn't give you the function declaration.  The return value of `GetProcAddress` is `FARPROC`.  It is then your responsibility to cast `FARPROC` to the appropriate function pointer type.  Windows does not help you -- you have to do this yourself.

Comment: `__stdcall FPtr_Device_RegisterDeviceEventHandler(const FPtr_DeviceEventHandler inHandler);` -- What is the actual function signature of `FPtr_DeviceEventHandler`? I don't see it anywhere in your post -- if we don't see this, then there is no way we know what you *should* be declaring.  Yes, you posted `EventNotice`, but we have no idea if this is the correct signature.  In C++, function signatures must match *exactly*, and that's why you're getting those errors.

Comment: @CherryDT : Thank you!!! This fixes the "left hand side" of the equation but the "right hand side" of the equation no longer works? ... I tried different "things" but I'm not sure what I need to do? I guess some "type casting" as well?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : Thanks for your help. I'm doing some research on casting the FARPROC. What a crazy world of "type", c++?

Comment: @RogerBreton -- You should use `typedef` to simplify the code.  For example, if the DLL function returns a LONG and takes two LONG parameters: `typedef LONG (__stdcall *Fn)(LONG, LONG);`, and then `Fn fn = reinterpret_cast<Fn>(GetProcAddress(dll, "funcname"));` and then to call the function `fn(100, 200);`.  And of course, all of those function return types, calling conventions, and parameters must already be known by you and match what the DLL expects.  All that responsibility falls into your hands -- the returning of the function pointer is all GetProcAddress helps with.

Comment: To me it sounds like you just need to make sure the LIB file is linked against. Probably some path is wrong and the LIB file isn't used. If the LIB file is used, everything works as you expect, without any manual shenanigans or needs for `LoadLibrary` in the first place.

Comment: Please post a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), instead of portions of code mixed with textual descriptions. Make sure to include the *Device\_RegisterDeviceEventHandler*, and handler functions signatures (the manufacturer must have provided them). Also, add relevant info in the question, not comments. What does "*I can effortlessly call all its functions from a MS Console application*" mean? If having a *.dll* that you want to "link against", you also need its corresponding *.lib*.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : I ended up following your suggestion of the typedef route. I ended up with three statements : 

typedef DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES(__stdcall* Fn2)(const FPtr_DEVICE_DeviceEventHandler inHandler);
Fn2 fn = reinterpret_cast<Fn2>(GetProcAddress(hInstance2, "DEVICE_RegisterDeviceEventHandler"));
deviceError = fn(EventNotice);
So far, the compiler seems happy with the syntax. Will give it a try soon but wanted to touch base and leave this comment for those other who might be looking for help in the same area. THANKS ONE MILLION!!!!!

Comment: @ChistiFati: I'm under NDA. So I can't just reference every line of code in this device sdk. This I can say, about the Console app; I have both the manufacturer .lib and .dll sitting in the same directory as the executable. Under Project Properties: I don't even have Device.dll under Additional Dependencies? I wish I could better understand WHY it works?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : Good news! I tried executing 'your' code and it seems to work. This is the result of the GetProcAddress call :
fn = DEVICE.dll!0x00007ffa67a1da20
And this is the result of executing the RegisterEventHandler :
sdkError = fn(EventNotice);
   // EventNotice = 0x00007ff739a21970 {WinTest.exe!EventNotice(DEVICE_EventCode, unsigned int, DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES)}
Wow! I'm flabbergasted! If this *actually* work, I mean... I'm going to be speechless. The DeviceHandler is the first step. Next step is to create typedef for the Connect DLL function : if the Connect functions, wow!!!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : I am making progress. Writing all original DLL functions into new typedefs. So far, so good!!!